# Android wear SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission for older version

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, sdk, wear-os

It seems that if I set targetSdkVersion to 26, when I require the draw over permission the app will always crash in Android wear 1.5, with "permission denied for this window type" because it doesn't have a runtime permission check like AW 2.0 does.

I found the same problem here: [Requesting permissions on Android wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524966/requesting-permissions-on-android-wear)

So I followed it and changed the wear gradle's targetSdkVersion to 22, and it works both fine on 1.5 and 2.0, it even doesn't ask for permission in 2.0.
BUT a big problem is that I can't update the app any more, it says "new target SDK 22 doesn't support runtime permissions but the old target SDK 26 does" You have to uninstall first.

[image: Can't update]

Does that mean if I publish it then no one can updated it on Play store anymore?

Or are there a better way to solve the first draw over (SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission instead of changing the targetSdkVersion?

Thank you!!!

Comment: As that dialog says, you can't downgrade `targetSdkVersion` in an app update. I believe that the Play dev console won't let you create an "update" with a lower `targetSdkVersion` than what you already have published - but it's been a while since I tried that.

Comment: Yes, so it is quite annoying, because the problem can't be solved unless creating a completely new app on the play console... Did you solve the problem at last?

Comment: in your Google+ post on this issue you said you hadn't uploaded the higher `targetSdkVersion` to Google Play. If that's true, then you don't have a problem.